# cakephp calling a model and if condition in view

Tags: if-statement, cakephp, scope

I have an articles table and an activationpages table and I want to call the activationpages table on my article controller so that my 'if statement' in my articles/view/add would work. it always say "undefined variable I'm a beginner at cakephp so please if someone could just help me.

here's my articles/controller code(I have commented my added codes)

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Article->create();
        if ($this->Article->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Article->User->find('list');
    $categories = $this->Article->Category->find('list');
    $statuses = $this->Article->Status->find('list');
    //$activationpage = $this->set('activationpage');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'categories', 'statuses'));
}
```

and here's my view/add "if statement"

```
<?php if ($activationpage['Activationpage']['studentstatus_id']==2): ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I asume that you have the table `activationpages`. When you use the following:
     `$this->loadModel('Activationpage');`
you can communicate with that table. This code creates the model in `$this->Activationpage`.

I did not get what you want to do with it next... Maybe you could give a clear explanation?

Comment: I would like to display the message if the studentstatus_id inside the activationpage model is equal to 2..... the activationpage model is associated with the student model... so whenever I deactivate the account of the student in which it is then recorded on the activationpage table the student can't submit... hence i have done the if statement on on the views/article/add.... thank you for helping... I have already done the find list and the SQL gets all the fields... takes too much time...